# Where to put compiled .jasper file

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Finally beeing able to compile `.jrxml` files to `.jasper` files,

how do I put them onto the server?

```
find / -iname "*.jasper"
(0 results)
```

I see they are not physically stored, they might be in the postgres database?

How to upload/deploy using 5.1.0 on Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I don't know why the question gets downvoted,
I see many people in need of help for that topic and all how to and resources on the internet are OUTDATED or for extreme Java nerds only.*

**I found out the solution:**

In the postgresql database there are 3 tables for Folders (`jiresourcefolder`), Resources (`jiresource`), ReportUnits (`jireportunit`) and the contents (blob) of those in `jifileresource`.

To import a ressource / file / folder into JasperServer, just INSERT into the database :-))))))